# XrmServiceToolkit Retrieve an Entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

A quick summary: From a Phone Call Activity I have a related Entity Contact, I then relate a Contact to an Account. So, from Phone Call I want to get some data from the related Contact's Account and do this by:

```
     var lookup = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue();
     XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Retrieve(lookup[0].id,
                'ContactSet',
                'ParentCustomerId',
                null,
                function (account) {
                    alert(String(account));
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert("in error handler");
                    alert(error.message);
                }, true);
```

Where ParentCustomerId is of type 'Entity' in Contact. I can get the Name of the account (by account.Name) and a few other (seemingly) random fields (none of which are the one I need), but not the ID of the account (which then I can use in another Retrieve).
Thoughts?

Comment: Try Soap: `var entity = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Retrieve("entityname", lookup.id, ["columns"]);`

Comment: Seems to work, so long as you set IE to compatibility IE 9 or lower, otherwise I get an error: 'Object doesn't support property or method 'selectSingleNode''.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do account.Name, then account.Id should be part of that same account object.  In the land of OData, capitalization matters, please ensure you are getting the id via "account.Id", not "account.id" or "account.ID"